# Force Firefox to reuse existing tab for modified HTML file

Tags: firefox, windows-7

If Firefox is already displaying a local HTML file on my PC in a tab (address = "file:///...") and I modify the file using my favorite external editor, sending the file to FF to display the edits results in FF opening a *new* tab with a fresh instance of the original file, rather than searching to see if the file is already open it it and reusing that tab.

Sure, after editing the file I could reopen Firefox, navigate along the tab bar to the existing tab for that file and click Refresh. But IMO FF should be capable of doing this for me. In my work, by the time I need to refresh FF, the tab currently open is not likely to be that of the file I am editing, so I continually need to return to the original page to refresh it.

My efforts to work around this include:

1)In about:config, *setting browser.link.open_newwindow* from 3 to 1.

2)Running Firefox and passing it either the filename or the URL to the filename (as *-url* parameter).

3)Looking for a suitable add-on.

I am not fond of either Firebug or Aurora and prefer my own editor (EditPlus), which with I am far more comfortable, to edit web pages. However, its inbuilt browser does not display properly on my screen, so I need to view results of edits in Firefox.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? I've searched here without success. The best solution would be another about:config setting. Thanks in advance.

(added) After all, in EditPlus, if I send it a file (in document-centric mode) which it has already opened, it simply changes focus to the existing tab. Why can't FF do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for suggesting the "Restore Open_External" add-on.

I tried it but it doesn't help me here. What it does is:

(quote)

"browser.link.open_external (Integer). This option specifies how Firefox opens links launched externally, e.g. e-mail or Microsoft Word. 3 options are available;

```
1. Selecting this option launches the link in a new tab in the most recently active Firefox window. This would be recommended if you don’t wish launching such links to affect your most recently active webpage and you aren’t concerned about the links content.

2. Selecting this option launches a new Firefox window to view the link. This would perhaps be the safest option to select (In that if you launch something questionable you may be able to end the process without affecting other windows).

3. Selecting this option (default) launches the link in the most recently active Firefox window/tab. This would be recommended if you aren’t concerned about launching links is the most recently active window/tab (You can always use the back button to view the previous page if you need)."
```

[TechSpot - Firefox 2 Tweak Guide](http://www.techspot.com/guides/44-firefox2-tweak-guide/page17.html)

I'm sure many find this useful. Option 1 would have been fine for my purposes if it didn't insist on opening a duplicate tab. This add-on does nothing to prevent duplicate tabs being opened. So I began hunting for some add-on that might PREVENT a new tab being created in response to an external app sending a file to Firefox. *Tab Mix Plus* is supposed to do this, but I got lost somewhere in the maze of options. Then there is Prevent Duplicate Tabs, which creates a whitelist of all pages where duplicates are not permitted. This is far from automatic and seems pretty lame to me, as is *Duplicate Tab Closer* which doesn't prevent a duplicate tab from being created; instead, you have to press Ctrl+Alt+D to remove existing duplicate tabs - equally lame. *deduplicate-tabs* is similar, but offers a button to remove duplicate tabs.

Maybe I'm missing the point, but I can't see why anyone would want duplicate tabs of the same page, one a later version than the other. In fact, FF ought to be able to automatically refresh a tab when one reselects this, without having to resort to the "refresh" button. But that's just my rant.

If anyone reading this can think of a better way to integrate FF with an external app that modifies a web page, I'll be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Install that addon:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restore-open_external/

Go to addon preferences and set:
'in the current tab of current window'

Next time you open a new url from an external program it opens in the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the 
[duplicate tabs closer firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/duplicate-tabs-closer/) which, as the name suggests, allows you to automatically close duplicate tabs

You can configure it to:

- Close the older tabs and keep the new tab
- Select the new tab

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://%20https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smart-prevent-duplicate-tabs/?src=search) addon.
I'm using it for development mode in Gatsby and Create React App.